# Which one is a better approach if any?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C from the C Programming Language book, in there, one of the exercises is to make a Fahrenheit to Celsius converter.

my code following the books style and instructions is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   float fhr;
   for (fhr = 0; fhr <= 300; fhr += 20)
      printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, (5.0/9.0)*(fhr-32));
}
```

It says in the book:
[image]

I just want to know if making a celsius variable and then calling it in the printf function as an argument is better or doing it this way is better, from both human readability and **more importantly if it makes any difference to the compiler** (I.e. makes the program run any faster or slower.)

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Comment: It's highly unlikely it makes any difference with modern compilers. The *preference* of which is better is subjective; either may be "better" depending on the complexity of the expression in question.

Comment: Which do you think would be easiest to debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a variable and then passing it to the printf would surely improve the readability.

From the compiler point of view there's no actual difference. It doesn't affect runtime performances in any way. This is especially true when it comes down to the internal optimizations the compiler carries out.

Comment: Okay, thanks. 
So basically since it doesn't do anything to the performance then it surely is better to make a variable and then pass it through since this style has a positive which is readability and no real negative.

Comment: Yes, I would do that

Answer (score 3):

From a compiler standpoint it potentially does have an impact. Depending on the compiler, it might see that the variable is only used once and "inline" the value anyway. Many may not, which would cause a hit to the overall performance. That being said, the performance hit would be inconsequential.

As for readability, storing it as its own variable would be easier to look at, and maintain later. Although for a small program like this, the difference is also pretty inconsequential; however, it might start making a difference in larger programs, especially if the value is going to be used more than once.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float fhr;
   for (fhr = 0; fhr <= 300; fhr += 20)
   {
      float celsius = (5.0/9.0)*(fhr-32);

      printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, celsius);
   }
}
```

You might also want to consider using a function, to abstract out how this value is determined. Again, this does create a hit to performance, and isn't necessary for such a small program, but would provide access to a way to determine the value from more places in the program. This would mean you would not need to rely on passing the value around, or having the variable within scope:

```c
float fahrenheit_to_celsius(float fhr)
{
    return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fhr - 32)
}

int main()
{
   float fhr;
   for (fhr = 0; fhr <= 300; fhr += 20)
   {
      float celsius = fahrenheit_to_celsius(fhr);

      printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, celsius);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a function for it, it won't be slower, and it's way better for readability (in my opinion)!

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fhr_to_cls(double fhr)
{
    return ((5.0 / 9.0) * ( fhr - 32));
}

int main()
{
   double fhr;

   for (fhr = 0; fhr <= 300; fhr += 20)
       printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, fhr_to_cls(fhr));
}
```

Comment: +1 for answer, there is a big reasons why this is the worst way to go. I do not think compiler will inline this function, you are using more memory, each function like this has to have memory for parameter and return value plus two jump statements for each call. what you can do is inline this function and you get rid of all of that. here is some guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-function-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I learned something today!

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
for (fhr = 0; fhr <= 300; fhr += 20)
  printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, (5.0/9.0)*(fhr-32));
```

the `0` and `300` and `20` and `32` are all `integers` that the code is trying to stuff into a `float`

the 5.0`and`9/0`are`doubles`

to correct all the above, Suggest:

```
for ( fhr = 0.0f; fhr <= 300.0f; fhr += 20.0f )
    printf("%3.1f %6.1f\n", fhr, (5.0f / 9.0f )*(fhr-32.0f));
```